# Weird characters appear when pressing command-A,C,V

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I'm not using Mac keyboard however it did work properly before. I changed the <kbd>Command</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Until today, using this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key yield extremely odd characters. When pressing

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> yields å
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> yields √
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> yields ç

And I have no idea where these characters come from? So how could I fix this issue? Can anyone please help? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here is my screenshot

[image: screenshot of keyboard preferences]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally configured your <kbd>control</kbd> key to be your <kbd>alt</kbd> key. Case in point: when I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I get å. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> returns √, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> gives us ç. Go into your settings and check again. They are located in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys. Note: <kbd>alt</kbd> is also <kbd>option</kbd>.

Edit: I cannot duplicate this phenomena (see comments on this answer), so I will guess that the non-Apple keyboard is messing up the process somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However no matter what I change, it will never become the `command key` again since I turn on the Keyboard Viewer and I saw that every time I assign a different key to `command`, it becomes option :(. Really don't know what to do now? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Chan That is odd. Let me play around with mine and see if I can duplicate what's going on.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ;). I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Chan No problem! Couldn't reproduce, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess I have to buy a Mac keyboard then. But it's totally weird since I set `command` to `no action` before. The only thing I did before that was reboot the computer from the command line since it was freeze. Other that, I couldn't think of any reason that would cause this problem.

Answer (score 12):

I've just run into that issue myself for my new Keychron K4 keyboard.
It turned out that the switch was pointing to Windows mode, rather than OSx.

Answer (score 1):

If the option key is the one with the Windows logo on it, make sure you have the game switch (the switch with the little joystick on it) set to off.  I think off is left.

With the game switch on, the Windows key is disabled (to prevent accidental Windows key presses from minimizing your game and sending you back to the Windows desktop).

Answer (score 1):

I use a Macbook Pro with an old PC keyboard and ran into this issue today,  <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> gives "ç".

After reading the posts here, I assigned

- Option to "No Action" and
- Command to Command

like this:

[image: Screenshot of Modifier configuration settings]

and now copy/paste works again.

This article has useful information:
[Command+C (copy) with the left command key does not work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108303/commandc-copy-with-the-left-command-key-does-not-work)

Comment: If Option key is set to Option instead of No Action, does that cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with my keyboard as below:

Ctrl-A yields å

Ctrl-V yields √

Ctrl-C yields ç

My problem was my keyboard settings.

I am using Air75 with both physically setting for MaxOS and Win.
The keyboard has a physical switch that allows you to select which system you are on. Flipping the switch to Windows will revert the command and options keys. I would suggest double check if you have the switch in the Windows setting.

I hope this helps, and best of luck.

Comment: Worked for me. I have Logitech K480 and the problem was that the OS switch was accidentally switched to Windows/Androin/Chrome mode. The moment I switched it to MacOS mode, it worked just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Logitech K860 I solved it by: Long press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

If that doesn’t work, then try <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

- not case sensitive
- long press (~ 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but today I ran into the same issue. What caused it, no idea. It was either a) my 1 year old daughter mashing keys or b) when trying to setup a steam controller on mac.

The problem is your option key and command key are swapped. Remapping the keys in the Settings > Keyboard > Modifier Keys doesn't work.

[Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) works to remap the keys to each other. Thus left option -> left command, left command -> left option. Same for the right side. Karabiner is a free, broadly used piece of software.

Here's what you'll want to do:

[image: Karabiner-Elements screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Some keyboards support different keyboard configurations.  I found pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> solved this problem on Mac.  See your specific keyboard manual to switch it to Mac layout.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System Preference -> Keyboard -> (Keyboard shortcuts) -> Modifier keys -> Restore setting for your keyboard*.

Then just press <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> for 3 seconds. Your keyboard setting will be setup to Mac defaults instead of Windows.