# Command+C (copy) with the left command key does not work

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm facing a strange problem. When I type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with the left command key, it does not work anymore. The left command key is working for <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or any others so it's not a hardware problem.

The <kbd>C</kbd> key is working too. The right command key is working for <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I tried changing keyboard language, adding a shortcut, reset NVRAM, activated/deactivated VoiceOver (tip found on a site) to no avail. I'm on a MacBook Pro with Mavericks.

Comment: Is this in only one app, or all apps?

Comment: It's on all apps. I created a new user, same problem.

Comment: Same problem here on OS X 10.10.2 with an external wired apple keyboard.

Comment: Yes, same here.  MBP 2019 on Big Sur.  Funny things are:  1) it's intermittent, i.e. if I repeat it twice I **do** get the copy and it *may* work on the 1st try.  2) Command right **always** works.  3) Command (left) V (paste) always works.  **Really Apple needs to get on the ball with this, it's been what, 9 yrs?.**

Answer (score 28):

Make sure when you press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> your `Edit` menu in the top flashes, this indicates it works as expected.

If it doesn't, go to *Keyboard* settings in *System Preferences* and:

- Restore defaults *Modifier Keys...*,
- Restore defaults in *Shortcuts* tab,
- In *App Shortcuts* click the *+* button and test if Keyboard Shortcut input box will react on your combination.

If `Edit` menu flashes and it still doesn't work, then the first thing to do is to restart pasteboard service by the following commands:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.pboard
launchctl start com.apple.pboard
```

If still doesn't work, here are some other suggestions to troubleshoot the problem:

- Re-test in different applications just in case.
- Re-test if works when using contextual menu (without using the shortcut).
- Re-test alternative combination such as <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for *Cut* instead.
- Run *Console* to see your *System log queries* if something obvious is happening.
- Test if the Clipboard works from the terminal via:

  ```
  $ echo test | pbcopy
  $ pbpaste
  ```

  If *Paste* menu item is no more greyed out, then maybe it's a problem with *Paste* command.

  If you're advanced user, use `dtruss` or `fs_usage` to debug it, for instance:

  ```
  $ sudo fs_usage | grep -C4 MyAppWhereCopyDoesntWork
  ```

  and then notice other apps which appearing exactly when you press the shortcut which potentially you could consider quitting for testing purposes.
- Disable any recent programs that you run or restart your computer.
- Disable *VoiceOver* as suggested [here](https://www.cnet.com/news/cmd-c-combination-stops-working-linked-to-speakable-itemsvoice-over/).
- Force quit the *Finder* (e.g.: `killall -HUP Finder`).
- If still doesn't work, consider rebooting the system, especially in Recovery or Safe mode to re-test.

As for a workaround, you can install [Karabiner app](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and [remap your shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252764/22781) by configuring [`private.xml` file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) (see *Misc* tab). For more suggestion, please check the following posts:

- [Remap Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and Ctrl-X only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66970/22781)
- [How can I reassign the copy/paste keyboard shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/32297/22781)

Comment: Adding in the combinations manually worked for all but `⌘` + `Z` for some reason. (Yes I am aware there is more to the answer I haven't tried yet; I just thought it was strange.)

Comment: Force quitting Finder made `⌘` + `C` stop working on the right too. But not any other commands strangely enough.

Comment: Running the commands

```
launchctl stop com.apple.pboard;
launchctl start com.apple.pboard
```
Fixed it for me

Comment: crazy that rebooting did not work, yet `launchctl stop com.apple.pboard
launchctl start com.apple.pboard` did

Comment: The terminal test is an excellent idea, and it reproduced the problem for me, so re-launching the pboard service was an obvious fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

One of your applications may utilize the cmd+c shortcut, which is not shown in system preferences.

I have GoldenDict installed and one of its hotkeys to "Use the following hotkey to translate a word from clipboard" is "cmd+c c", which brings this problem.

**Solution: use another hotkey or disable it.**

Comment: Same here. I had GoldenDict installed and hence it was interfering

Answer (score 5):

What has worked for me was force-quitting Finder (basically after trying all what you have suggested yourselves).

Comment: This solved my problem too! Strange things happen!

Answer (score 4):

It was a weird experience for me, had the same problem. After long unfruitful research through internet, I took MBP to the Genius Bar. Even they tried with networked operating systems like 10.9, 10.8 and others too. Nothing worked, later after long technical discussion they decided it may be an hardware issue (due to shorting, also option button was not working during startup OS switching). After top keyboard cover replacement it worked! Again something unexplainable, yet worked!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. What do you mean by replacing the keyboard cover? Do you mean the plastic keys?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because "Command+C" in **Input Sources** conflicted with "Command+C" of Copy command.

I went "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources", and found "Select the previous input source" item, then changed it to "Control+C". Then the "Command+C" Copy command worked.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your insights! after clearing the cache, resetting PRAM, repairing disc and permission, nothing.  Then it worked for a few minutes. Finally, I decided to use Keyremap4macbook and assigned the fn key to work like left command. It works, so I leave it like that. Problem half solved...

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts**
2. Select **Restore Defaults** after selecting each menu item on the left

Answer (score 2):

I talked to the Apple support and reset my hardware by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd> and the power button at the same time. Then release everything. To restart your computer, just press on the power button again.

It doesn't damage anything and even got back on the internet pages I was on.

Comment: it's work for me, 

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and went into System Preferences>Shortcuts>Keyboard and deselected everything. I was having issues with cmd-z, cmd-x, cmd-v, and deselecting all of these (I didn't use them anyway) allowed all of these to work again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Keyboard
3. Select Shortcuts
4. Select Keyboard
5. Select Move focus to next window
6. Click on the key combination
7. Set it to whatever you want

Comment: what does "Move focus to next window" have to do with this question?

Comment: Legend!! I was having a similar problem. Couldn't use Cmd + 1 . just wouldn't work on anything but I only used it the other day, followed your instructions and deselected "Move focus to next window" TADA!!! fixed! thankyou. don't know why you were down voted. Just because it didn't work for you, don't down vote a correct answer. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You might have a wrong keyboard layout set up on your system, i.e. Dvorak keyboard layout. If you switch to the proper layout you might fix the problem.

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources. Then click on "+" and add the keyboard layout of your preference.

Note:
Dvorak users should know that there are a few types of the keyboard: Dvorak, Dvorak - Left, Dvorak - Right, Dvorak - Qwerty. Each of those acts differently when combination "Command + C" is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Funny trick to make it work:

System Pref > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts (left sidebar).

Add a new item "Copy" and type the shortcut CMD C.

***It works!***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after one copy command (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) with the right command key, the left command key started working again!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It shall be not a real answer but it is still a solution for The problem, Master.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - my right command-c does actually work, so this is interesting. left command-v works fine

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue due my [ongoing struggles with the keyboard of a late-2016 MBP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272038/macbook-pro-2016-keyboard-key-stuck-how-to-remove-key):

`cmd + c` suddenly stopped working. The problem was the `esc` key, which remained pressed because of some *minor* piece of dirt. With blowing and pressing the key repeatedly it returned to its normal position and `cmd + c` started working again.

<sup>(Now I have to solve  issues with two other keys. Don't buy this  piece of hardware, the keyboard will give you pain. Mine was already replaced, but new piece is also prone to keyboard damages due to dust and other small pieces of dirt you encounter in every office and every household. It's just bad design.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
On top of the problem with not having <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, after a while I wasn't able to do a capital "E" by holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>...after a while more than 10 random keys activated "mission control"...so you can imagine my frustration.

...but luckily I sorted.

The problem was with Lightroom Classic CC and once I did restart preferences in LR everything was ok again.
If you using the newest LR CC 8. Try Maybe it work for you.

Reset Procedure:

1. Close Lightroom.
2. Hold down <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while restarting Lightroom.
3. Overwrite the Preferences when prompted by the dialogue.
4. Close Lightroom.
5. Restart Lightroom.

Comment: I dont think it is the programs fault. I dont use these.

Answer (score 0):

I had such an issue on macOS Big Sur but when I updated it to Monterey it was solved.

Please try updating your OS.

Comment: Updating to Sonoma 14.1.1 literally created this issue, so this is not a great answer

Answer (score -2):

This issue is real and I think every mac user experience it on a weekly basis, but likely people continue to doubt themselves over if they actually command c or not properly.

**The fix.** If you are using Karabiner like real hacker should:

Just add this to your karabiner complex configurations:

```
[
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "c",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    }
]
```

Now that should make the copy flash a few times in the menu.

You can increase or decrease as much as you want. Personally I have a few more.