# MacbookPro 2016 butterfly keys: Where are claws and hooks on "up" and "down" cursor keys

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, macos

I've successfully removed a regular key following the advice from
[MacBook Pro 2016: Keyboard key stuck – how to remove key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272038/macbook-pro-2016-keyboard-key-stuck-how-to-remove-key/300952#300952)

I'm considering doing the same with up/down keys but not 100% sure if the attachment mechanism is the same - claws on bottom, and hooks on the top. Can please somebody confirm it?