# Re-attach the butterfly mechanism on MacBook Pro keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I was trying to remove a key on the Delete key on my Macbook Pro with TB 2016 model. Unfortunately I pulled out the butterfly mechanism as well while removing the key with a plastic card. Now I am unable to attach the key back. Is there a way to do it without visiting the Apple Store?

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: Take a look at [the question and answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/272038/88313).  Included in some of the answers are (limited) instructions on reattaching the key.