# How do you fix a non-working key on the Macbook pro 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a Macbook pro 2016 and keys keep getting stuck. By "stuck" I mean that pressing them doesn't do anything anymore unless I press them really hard. The recommended way is to blow air into the keyboard while holding it at a certain angle. I never have a can of air laying around, and blowing with my mouth doesn't seem to work. Is there a different way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MacBook Pro 2016: Keyboard key stuck – how to remove key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272038/macbook-pro-2016-keyboard-key-stuck-how-to-remove-key)

Comment: Replace the top case.

Comment: Bring it into an Apple Store or setup a mail-in repair and they will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way that seems to work and doesn't require a can of air: Hold the laptop sideways and while holding it like that, pound on the key. Pound as hard as you would if you were typing an angry message. Try to pound on each side of the key. Holding it sideways gives gravity a chance to pull the crumbs out. And if it doesn't work the first time, try holding it a different direction.

I've tried this method on several keys, including the large right SHIFT key. It seems to work pretty good. The SHIFT key still isn't fully back to normal, but is way better than it was.

Comment: Just a heads up, while this may work, it may very well also cause damage to your laptop. If I were you, I'd look into ways of removing a key to clean under it, then reapplying it.

Comment: How would this cause any damage, as long as you aren't pounding harder than the keyboard was designed for?

Comment: Because the keyboard was not designed to be held sideways and pounded. Using things outside their intended scope always leaves them susceptible to damage.

Comment: I only had to type as though I was mildly disappointed to get it to work.  Please don't remove the key, as that is more likely to void the warranty than typing.  Also, obviously, don't pound the key hard enough to cause damage.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to Apple, who will do a free repair under their [keyboard service program](https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/).

Comment: Yes. Have done this before and will probably need to do it again. It's just a hassle and I was hoping to find a way to minimize these trips.