# Command + C does not always work on first try on MacOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, copy-paste

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> does not always work on first try on any of my four Macs.  I often highlight text, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, head to another window, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> only to find that the original text did not copy.

I recently installed a fresh copy of macOS High Sierra and I continue to run into this issue, particularly in RStudio.<sup>*</sup> The issue never occurs on my PCs.

**Do others have this issue? How can I resolve this?**

<sup>*</sup>I use bettersnaptool and enable three finger dragging, but the issue still appears when I disable them.

Comment: Did you mean to paste using Command-V or Command-P? [Command-P is generally reserved for print and Command-V is the shortcut for paste.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: Do you have any other utilities running which could interfere with your keyboard?

Comment: I face the same issue. I don't have any utilities that interfere with the keyboard. @RTS Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Problem is not solved. I recently ran into the problem while using computers at the Apple store. It seems ever-present.

Comment: I observed this issue on a demo machine at the Apple store recently. I suppose it must not concern most people.

Comment: Which keyboard language setting are you using - US English?, US International or something different? I have no such problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108303/commandc-copy-with-the-left-command-key-does-not-work?rq=1

Comment: Sure you really press command-C? Maybe your muscle memory keeps on pressing ctrl-C instead?

Comment: @Philippos this happens way too often. I noticed it happening on new colleagues computers as well. It is real. I already been into the self doubt stage. The command is registered in karabiner even viewer as well. See my solution below.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's possible for Apple's Continuity [Universal Clipboard](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209460) feature to cause something like this, depending on the quality of the signal connection with any nearby iOS devices.

Perhaps try turning off "Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices" in System Preferences > General and see if that helps.

Comment: FWIW I do not use the Universal Clipboard, have not even set up the conditions/requirements for it 's use, and still have the issue described in the OP.

Comment: Sadly, it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a cause of the same problem. An app may use it as a hotkey. In my case, I use a dictionary app (Eudic), which will read the clipboard if cmd+c is pressed twice.

An easy way to check whether it is caused by an app is to activate the Guest account, which usually has few autostart apps, and to check whether the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this for a long time too and I thought it was because that my laptop was old, but apparently not.

I found that if I slow down a little bit, like hold the command key for 1 about 1 second, and then hit C, it would work.

However, I don't know the cause behind or a real fix.

Answer (score -2):

This issue is real and I think every mac user experience it on a weekly basis, but likely people continue to doubt themselves over if they actually command c or not properly.

**The fix.** If you are using Karabiner like real hacker should:

Just add this to your karabiner complex configurations:

```
[
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "c",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key_code": "c",
                "modifiers": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    }
]
```

Now that should make the copy flash a few times in the menu.

You can increase or decrease as much as you want. Personally I have a few more.

Comment: Does this actually „fix“ the problem, or rather spare the user to press cmd-c several times to compensate for it?

Comment: I am not sure, I have not really put it into action to notice it yet. However, the user might not be aware the command-c was picked up, hence the reason why it is repeated to ensure it is. Often times, the command-c is done. A switch to another window, some clicking, editing, and then command-v not to be seen. If the user knew command-c was not picked up, no it is not required as as he can reinvoke it (which is not the same), this just invokes it a bunch of times to make sure the os picks it up.

Comment: Being an early adopter of Mac OS X, I did never experience this in all the years, not even a single time. And if this happened to a lot of users regulary, it would be discussed widely everywhere. But it‘s not, so your introduction is at least misleading. If the problem is real, only a tiny minority of users can be affected, and it‘s neccessary to find out some configuration as common cause (like the other answers did) instead of trying a hack as workaround …

Comment: Well, the problem is most people think it is due to them. I noticed it within 1 week of being exposed to others that it is very real. It happens to all. They also confirmed it. That it is not reported is not relevant. I am allowed to state whatever I want, and it is reported quite a lot as well. I simply always figured maybe i was not pressing hard  enough.

Comment: Also, it could be due to some setting or handsoff. Perhaps you are not using that. Pboard? Keyboard maestro, perhaps. Who knows. It does happen though. It is kind of difficult to pin down though cause it does not happen all the time.