Why do I always have to press Command-C twice for the Command-V paste action to work?
Has anyone explained what kind of System/Settings attribute needs to change to make Cmd+C work as expected? -- which would be:

highlight-select string to copy

press Cmd+C combo-key

press Cmd+V to paste copied item at the cursor position


Is there some terminal command that forces Cmd+C to copy selected text the first time so that then Cmd+V pastes the selected text?  I've been a Mac user since 1986 and having to perform Cmd+C twice is illogical.

You need to select first and then copy. From documentation: “Command-C: Copy the selected item to the Clipboard. This also works for files in the Finder.”. If nothing selected then nothing is copied.

Does this happen in all applications you are using? Does it happen also if you use another keyboard?

MacOS has always copied the selected text to the Pasteboard using Command C. You should not need to press it twice. If you Paste when text is selected, that text will be replaced. It has been like that at least since 1986. Are you saying that this is not how it behaves for you?

You need to swap the order of steps 1 and 2.

SteveM added a post some weeks ago explaining the process for copying text. Could you check it out? If it helps, it'd be great if you could mark it as the accepted answer to help others with a similar issue.

RE: "MacOS has always copied the selected text to the Pasteboard using Command C. You should not need to press it twice. If you Paste when text is selected, that text will be replaced. It has been like that at least since 1986. Are you saying that this is not how it behaves for you?" — — — —
Nine times out of 10 this happens, where the initial CMD-C does not take. Others on Reddit have corroborated these aberrations, but no one here has experienced it apparently. Thanks.

Re: this behavior of having to sometimes hit COMMAND-C twice in order for the item to hit the pasteboard, which is in denial based on answers here, please you can see in the "related questions" at Column Right a prior thread from 6 years ago that describes same:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324223/command-c-does-not-always-work-on-first-try-on-macos?rq=1 .. Is everyone there wrong?

User experiences are never „wrong“. But having to press Cmd-C twice is not standard behavior of macOS, so something on the system is „wrong“ for sure. Both the old Q&A and this one here offer ideas about the cause.

For macOS, the steps are out of order. You must first select the text to copy (your step 2) then click Cmd+C (your step 1). Thus the correct process is:

select the item to copy
press Cmd+C to copy the selected item
press Cmd+V to paste the copied item at the cursor position

This is the expected behavior in macOS.
Thus we see why you need to press Cmd+C twice. The first time, it copies 'nothing' as nothing was selected to copy. The second time the selected text is copied.

Closing this thread is the height of arrogance. I pointed out the "other thread" because I was illustrating people care about this issue and find it to be "REAL".  But that thread did not SOLVE the question. So makes great sense that you close THIS one, penalizing my right to have a problem solved, and then point to the thread that never solved the issue.

I may be arrogant at times, but I had nothing to do with closing this thread. Cheers.
